# css sytelsheet not being applied to php code

Tags: php, html, css

so I have quite a messy CSS / PHP / HTML situation.
Basically something works on one php script but not the other.

My Code is as follows (its just one part of it):

```
 <?php
         if ($daten->getData_DB_User($get_page_num) != false) {
         ?>
            <div class="seiten_vor_zur">
            <br>
                <td> <div class="seitenanzahl">
                          <button disabled>Seite : <?php echo $get_page_num ?></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?q=lesen&seite=" . $get_last_page; ?>"
                           role="button">Vorherige Seite
                    </a>
                </td> &nbsp;
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?q=lesen&seite=" . $get_next_page; ?>"
                           role="button">Nächste Seite
                    </a>
                </td>
            <?php
            }
            else{
                echo "Es gibt keine weiteren Einträge.<p> <a 
    href='javascript:window.history.back()'>Zurück</a> </p>";
            }
            ?>
            </div>
```

Now my problem is that I'm trying to style the last p and a element in the div box class="seiten_vor_zur".
My Page does not use the CSS entries and I'm wondering why?

Here's the CSS entry:

```
    .seiten_vor_zur{
    
        text-align: center;
    
    }
    .seiten_vor_zur a{
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #05128f, 0 0 25px #ffffff, 0 0 5px #ffffff;
    
    }

    .seiten_vor_zur a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #05128f;
    }
    .seiten_vor_zur a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(6, 161, 227, 0.4);
    }
```

Comment: Your `html` and `CSS` look OK, the CSS should apply to the html. The problem is probably that the CSS is not applied to the page in question, but that's hard to debug based in these snippets.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any css file linked to your php file. add import your css file to your php file and see if it load or not

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_css_file.css">
```

or use inline css just to see it working first.